# WordPress XMLRPC - Search Post by Slug and Update

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Is there anyway to search posts by slug through XMLRPC
https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.getPosts

**getPosts()** doesn't seem to return using "name"..

```
$args = array(
   'name'   => 'my-slug',
   'number' => 1
);
    
$post = $wpClient->getPosts( $args );
```

Please let me know if there is a workaround for this, I need to search by slug and then update those slugs remotely via XMLRPC. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Methods, this may help someone and save time.. paste the following code in functions.php of the domain you are fetching data from

```
 add_filter('xmlrpc_methods', 'clx_xmlrpc_methods');
 function clx_xmlrpc_methods($methods) {
     $methods['getPostBySlug'] = 'clx_getpost';
     return $methods;
 }

 function clx_getpost($args) {
     global $wp_xmlrpc_server;

     $slug = $args["slug"];
     $pargs = array(
       'name'        => $slug,
       'post_type'   => 'post',
       'numberposts' => 1
     );

     $my_posts = get_posts($pargs);
     if( $my_posts ) :
       return $my_posts; //echo $my_posts[0]->ID;
     endif;
 }
```

from your XMLRPC code use the following to get POST array from slug

```
    $args = array(
      'slug'   => 'your-post-slug'
    );
    
    $postArray = $wpClient->callCustomMethod( 'getPostBySlug', $args );
```